# Determining salary for a niche skill

Tags: software-industry, salary

I am a software engineer with 2 years experience. I have been working a lot with NFC in that time and consider myself to have a good level of knowledge on the topic.

I also consider NFC to be a niche area of software engineering, and (with this in mind) wonder how to interpret salary surveys.

For a niche area like NFC should one expect a higher salary than what is offered for more common skills e.g. mobile development?

For example, salary surveys might mention figures of 30-40k for a mobile developer. Is it reasonable for me to try and leverage my NFC knowledge and expect a slightly higher scale.

How does this work?

Comment: really depends on location and the amount of competition for that sort of role

Comment: There can also be the factor of what companies could pay as some start-ups may prefer to pay in options that may be harder to price.

Answer (score 3):

Having a niche skill has pros and cons: The pro is that you are the only one with a skill and cannot be easily replaced, the con is that the skill has no value whatsoever unless someone is looking exactly for that skill.

So quite obviously you should either charge more for that skill, or give up on it and gain more generally useful skills.